# Default Image Style

Tags: wpf, image, styles

It was my understanding that this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
  <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="None"/>
  <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
  <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Help"/>      
</Style>
```

would change the default image settings for each image rendered on the Window.  Is this not the case?  Is there an exception for images as it appears to work with other controls?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a style for a type you actually need to set the x:Key attribute like so:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type Image}" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
    <!-- setters here -->
</Style>
```